# prevent UINavigatonBar from overlapping content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

The problem I have is only with iOS7. 
I have a `UINavigationController` which includes a `UITableView`. The NavigationBar is on top of the table content. So far so good. As soon as I click on a cell I show a `UIViewController`. As it slides in the NavigationBar is overlapping the ViewControllers content and at the bottom of the view I have an empty space (size of NavBar).

How can I get the same old behavior as of iOS6? I don't want the NavBar to be translucent in any way.

Comment: Just select 6.1 as the base SDK. This will give you iOS 6 behaviour on any device.

Comment: how can I do that with xCode5? Actually I want my app to use iOS7 functions.

Comment: Ah, then you have to set... `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` on the view controller.